# Ansible fails to create temporary directory

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am trying to use a jumpbox to reach my target VM on ansible.
I have the following file structure

```
play.yaml
hosts
  serverA
  serverB
  testServers/
    serverX
    serverY
    group_vars/
      all.yml
```

`server[X,Y]` host file contains

```
[serverType]
1.2.3.4
```

`all.yml` file under `hosts/testServers/` contain

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: key.priv
proxy_user: myServiceAccount
proxy_user_key: key.priv
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i {{ proxy_user_key }} -W %h:%p -q {{ proxy_user }}@{{ bastion_host }}
```

I have a ping module in `play.yaml`

```
- hosts: all  
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - action: ping
```

I run the following command

```
ansible-playbook -vvvv play.yaml -i hosts/testServers/serverX 
  -e ansible_ssh_user="$LDAP_USER" -e ansible_ssh_pass="$LDAP_PASS" 
  -e ansible_become_pass="$LDAP_PASS"
  -e bastion_host="$BASTION_NAME"
```

I get the following error

```
Failed to create temporary directory.In some cases, you may have
been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the
target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in
ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error
information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p
\"` echo /tmp `\"&& mkdir
/tmp/ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304 && echo
ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304=\"` echo
/tmp/ansible-tmp-1626262883.727861-210-80403864334304 `\" ),
exited with result 6
```

---

To consider

- the ssh_user has permissions to rwx permissions on /tmp
- the `remote_tmp` is set to `/tmp` in ansible.cfg
- the ssh configs are set correctly on the source VM and the keypairs are working as expected by following this tutorial https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2020/10/26/use-a-ssh-jump-host-with-ansible/

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to misconfiguration. When using Ansible (it doesnt't matter, either Linux or WSL or Mobaxterm controller) it should be checked always:

1. /etc/hosts - contains proper line `12.34.56.78 inventory_host`. First check this point.
2. ansible_ssh_private_key_file - points to proper ssh private key (.key, not putty format)
3. files in .ssh folder - have proper permissions (chmod -R 600)

For debug run `ansible -i inventory_file -m ping inventory_host -u ssh_user -vvv` or `-vvvv`. Usually it says what's the problem.

.

For those who has problems to begin using Ansible, here it is good ansible settings (3 steps to begin working):

1. compose `ansible.cfg` located in project folder

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./inventory
interpreter_python = auto_silent
verbosity = 1

# first disable 'requiretty' in /etc/sudoers
ANSIBLE_PIPELINING = True

retry_files_enabled = False
deprecation_warnings = False
system_warnings = True
command_warnings = False
error_on_undefined_vars = True
display_args_to_stdout = True
display_skipped_hosts = True
gather_subset = !hardware,!facter,!ohai

# logger
log_path = ansible_log.rb

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPersist=60s -o ConnectTimeout=10
retries = 1
usetty = True
sftp_batch_mode = True
transfer_method = sftp

[diff]
always = True
```

These options allow skip inventory and add some useful options by default (supress warnings, more verbose output and diff).

For mobaxterm-based ansible controller the user probably needs do:

```
sed -i '/Ciphers/s/^/#/g' /etc/ssh_config
sed -i '/MACs/s/^/#/g' /etc/ssh_config
```

because of incorrect lines in distro.

2. inventory

```
[all:vars]
# common variables

ansible_user=ssh_user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/{{ ansible_user }}/.ssh/id_rsa

[group1:vars]
# variables for group1 servers

[group2:vars]
# variables for group2 servers

[group1]
host[1:2]

[group2]
host[3:4]

[prod:children]
group1
group2
```

This means that your environment has 4 servers in 2 groups, all of them are called as `prod`. You may -ping- them by groups or at once.

For Windows SSH remote servers add to inventory:

```
ansible_shell_type=powershell
shell_type=powershell
```

or use `-e ansible_shell_type=powershell`

Do not forget set default shell `powershell` on remote before connecting (pwsh example):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

or older:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

3. /etc/hosts

```
ipadress1 host1
ipadress2 host2
ipadress3 host3
ipadress4 host4
```

Then you can check:

```
ansible -m ping host1
ansible -m setup prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran `ansible -m ping [hostname] -vvv` and the extra detailed output provded but the "-vvv" flag showed that the default password for the ansible user had expired and needed to be changed for the ssh connection to succeed. Simply logging on to the remote host and changing the password (`passwd [user]`) for the use worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).